# Mobile App authentication for admin actions

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework

I am developing an application where users are playing a game and upon completion their results are sent to my back end through a POST request. Since I do not want this POST request to be done manually by someone who finds this endpoint (and mess with his results), I need a way to restrict it so that it can be done only through the application. However is it safe to hardcode a token that provides this access?
What is the correct way to go around this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use hard-coded tokens, if the token gets compromized, you have to change the server as well as the client.

I would recommend some sort of auth mechanism as JWT with ssl with one rudimentary username/password system.